# Angular Console Logging with --prod

Tags: angular

Just finishing up my first major angular (7) project and noticed that that when I build with the "--prod" switch, I no longer see console logging in my application.  For general usage this is fine, but we do have a logging service that will be used by support that can be enabled and needs to be able to log to the console.

I did remove "no-console" from my tslint file.

I'm hoping that one of the angular guru's here will be able to point me in the right direction.

Jason

Comment: `console.log()` is not silenced when you use `---prod`. So if there is no console output it's likely because the app is logging a different way and there is a flag to disable it in production. Search the source code for `environment.production`

Comment: Strange because there is a very definite difference when I use the --prod flag.  I did as you suggested and the only instance of environment.production in my project is if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

Comment: Is your app using `console.log()` or a special service for logging?